# sorting children node in tree layout d3js

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, visualization

I start to learn d3.js at the moment. And I would like to sort my children nodes (json format data) in the tree layout. I have seen some sorting tutorials however it does not seem to fit in my case, because I want to perform the sort specifically in the children levels. Would any one please give me a hint/sample for that ?

Bests

Comment: Have you seen the [`.sort()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#sort)?

Comment: yes and still trying to find the way to specifically sort children level of the tree layout

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the children"?

Comment: figured it out using tree.sort() in d3 thanks